# Mini Panel Title Question for each region

Tags: panels

Is there a way to move the title of each region to the side? instead of on the top having it go down the side of each region?

i.e
 Region 1   Region 2
T           T
E           E
S           S
T           T

Comment: Not sure what you're asking... maybe include a screenshot?  I have a feeling it's based on your admin theme.